# show that $\cosh x \geq1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Can someone help me show that $\cosh \geq1$.

I know that $\cosh x = \frac{1}{2}(e^x+s^{-x})$

I think I'm supposed to use the identity: $\cosh^2x - \sinh^2x=1$

Comment: Try to differentiate the expression for $coshx$ and you see that its minimum value is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $$\cosh^2 x =1+\sinh^2 x \ge 1$$
So $\cosh^2 x \ge 1$. Since $\cosh x$ is positive, we have $$\cosh x \ge 1$$
Done! You could also say $$\cosh x =\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \ge \sqrt{e^{x} \times e^{-x}}=1$$
From [$\text{AM-GM}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: I tried this: http://mathb.in/127894 , but I was told that I assume what I try to prove.

Comment: @tonytouch So you aren't given $\cosh^2 x -\sinh^2 x=1$?

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed to use that.

Comment: @tonytouch Is my edit sufficent?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! I can first accept your answer in 4 min! but the link I showed you, was that wrong? I posted it on an irc forum and I was told it was wrong.

Comment: @tonytouch No, I think that it should be right. Perhaps you should be elaborating on how $$\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$$ And why $\cosh x>0$, as $$\cosh^2 x \ge 1$$ merely implies $\cosh x \le -1$ or $\cosh x \ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

by AM-GM we get : $$\frac{1}{2}(e^x+e^{-x})\geq \sqrt{e^x\cdot e^{-x}}=1$$

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Dr. Sonnhard